# Python: concatenate 2 list

Tags: python, arraylist

I have 2 lists in python:

```
list1 [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]

list2 [a,b,c,d,e,f,-,-,-,-]
```

I would like to output the follow:

output

```
[a,b,-,-,c,d,-,-,e,f]
```

I am lost, tried multiple things without any luck.
Anyone have an idea how to do it? Here's my try:

```
for e in range (0, len(stringas)):
  if controllo[e] == "1":
    memoria.append(stringas[e])
  if controllo[e] == "0":
    memoria.append("-")
    blocco.append(e)
    salva.append(stringas[e])

print (stringas)
print (memoria) 

for f in salva:
  print (blocco[c])
  print (salva[c])
  memoria.insert(blocco[c], salva[c])
  c = c + 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you describe what your code is supposed to do please?

Comment: Please explain a bit more the algorithm to get the result from the two lists

Comment: I try to describe it a little better:

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
output = [list2.pop(b-1) for b in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
for i in list1:
    out.append(list2.pop(0) if i else '-')
```

Comment: you can replace '-' with list2.pop(-1) if you always have the '-' signs t the end of the list2

Answer (score 0):

Or even this one liner:

```
list1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]

list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','-','-','-','-']

output = [list2[i] if v else '-' for i, v in enumerate(list1)]

print(output)
```

**UPDATE Not quite a one liner and could be more efficient in the for loop - but I prefer this readbility**

```
list1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

output = []

j = 0

for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    output.append('-' if not v else list2[j])
    j = j if not v else j+1

print(output)
```

Comment: This will not work as the i value increments. In your example, you will miss out 'c', 'd' altogether which is not intended by OP :-)

Comment: Oh darn - course it will - I blame the lack of morning caffeine today!

Comment: That's better-ish!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think this is what you want.

For each element in list1, if the element is a 1, add the next element in list2 to newList. If it's a 0, add a hyphen to newList.

```
list1 = [   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   0 ]
list2 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ] # idk why you needed hyphens in this list
newList = [ ]

i = 0
j = 0
for i in range (len(list1)):
    if list1(i) == 1:
        newList += [ list2(j) ]
        j++
    if list1(i) == 0:
        newList += [ '-' ]
return newList

# output: [ '-', '-', 'a', 'b', 'c', '-' ]
```

Unless your goal is that if the element in list1 is a 1, add the next element from the beginning of list1 to newList, and if it's a 0, add the next element from the end. This will not guarantee that the 0s create corresponding hyphens.

```
list1 = [   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   0 ]
list2 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', '-', '-', '-' ]
newList = [ ]

i = 0
start = 0
end = len(list2) - 1

for i in range (len(list1)):
    if list1(i) == 1:
        newList += [ list2(start) ]
        start += 1
    if list1(i) == 0
        newList += [ list2(end) ]
        end -= 1
return newList

# output: [ '-', '-', 'a', 'b', 'c', '-' ]
```

Comment: Perfect, you came in my head and exit with the right solution ;)
Thank you and how much years of experience do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this program should be as follow:
1. If the current element in list1 is 1, pop the first element from list2
2. If not, pop the last element from list2

Here is a sample code for your reference:

```
list1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
list2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","-","-","-","-"]
outList = []

for index in range(len(list1)):
    # If the current value of list1 element is 1, pop from the first
    if list1[index] == 1:
        outList.append(list2.pop(0))
    # If the current value of list1 element is 0, pop from the last
    else:
        outList.append(list2.pop(-1))

for item in outList:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 scenarios how the output described comes:

1) If the first list has 0, just add '-'

```
list1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '-', '-', '-']
index =0
output = []
for element in list1:
    if element != 0:
        element = list2[index]
        index += 1
    else:
        element = '-'
    output.append(element)
```

2) If the '0' in list 2 represents element from the end

```
list1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '-', '-', '-']
list3 = list2[:]
output = []
for element in list1:
    if element != 0:
        element = list3.pop(0)
    else:
        element = list3.pop(-1)
    output.append(element)
```